# Graphic view of spring xml in intellij

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

I noticed the spring plugin from eclipse shows the xml in a graphic form instead of code.
Is there a similar way in intellij to do this. Or is it just code view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Right click on your application context file -> select `Diagrams` -> `Show Diagram...`